# Advice for Math Proof Language

Tags: java, c#, arrays, math

Trying to figure out if I wanted to run a number 17 digits long through 50 million divisions how long would it take on a decent i7 PC and what would you recommend for language? Also I would like to scale it up over time so need a language that can be flexible when I get to say 30ish digit long numbers. For now basically I begin with a 17 digit long number and as I go I only care about the a smaller number after each calculation so it will get smaller quick. I am only doing division and subtraction and not keeping any remainders. Thoughts?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: "Can someone help me" was not the question. It was what the best language to get a basis so I don't begin this very long process (will take maybe years to get where I want to go) off the wrong way. It's nice someone actually gave great advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've knocked up a quick program to test how long it takes, here I believe I have used a 20 digit long number. I know it's not exactly the parameters that you have asked for, however it gives a good illustration to what kind of speed you can be expecting.

This was run on a i5-6200U @ 2.30GHz

[image: 50 Million Operations]

If you are interested on the code that I used here it is. It will not be able to divide 30 digits but a little tweaking will allow it to. This is written in C#.

```
using System;

namespace _50_Million
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Number ");
            string number = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("What to divide by ");
            string divide = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("How many times ");
            string d = Console.ReadLine();

            decimal previousNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(number);
            decimal times = Convert.ToDecimal(d);
            decimal divideDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(divide);
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            decimal newNumber = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            {
                    newNumber = previousNumber / divideDecimal;
                    previousNumber = newNumber;           
            }

            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            Console.WriteLine("It has taken " + elapsedMs + " millisecounds to divide " + number + " by " + divide + ", " + d + " times.");
            Console.WriteLine("The Answer is " + newNumber);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. The goal is to run different numbers based on a list of numbers against said number or the product (result) of calculations. Thus reducing the number every hit. It's a great start and gives me the direction I require. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I had another question - to add to this one but a further concept for what I am working on. I have spent years on this method by hand and I apologise if it is second nature to so many to automate. Apparently I am banned from asking questions now as this got a lot of down thumbs. Kind of disappointing as I always reference this site and first time I took a punt to ask for help and guidance. Thanks Max for your guidance. I will assign my team to write it in C# to prove what I did works. Wanted to see if there were any methods similar as I can't find any, guess I can't ask.